# How to connect signal from nested qml item from c++ code?

Tags: c++, qml, signals-slots

I have a UI written in QML. The UI contains a TextEdit nested somewhere deep in the tree. I want to connect the signal onTextChanged to my c++ logic in the background. How can I access the *nested* signal from c++?

Comment: Kind of a difficult question since we don't know what your code looks like. The answer is basically "expose a signal at a high enough level in QML that your C++ object can connect to it".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a design issue, you shouldn't really access QML from C++, it is best to keep the interaction one way - access the exposed C++ API from QML only.

In your case, instead of making the connection on the C++ side, you can simply install a handler for the signal in QML:

```
onTextChanged : cppLogic.callCPPfoo()
```

This is faster, easier, more flexible and can pass data even if the signal doesn't have data parameters.